Use Colab to copy / rename Google Drive files
I have created 3 google sides templates (Z_WRx1_x.gslides,Z_WRx2_x.gslides,Z_WRx3_x.gslides). I want to make copies of them for several chapters in a book.
I've mounted Google Drive, but cannot get Colab to copy the files. I've tried shutil.copyfile() and .copy() and .copy2():
import shutil

chapter = 3
topics = ['African','Hinduism']

for topic in topics:
  for dow in range(1,4):
    shutil.copyfile(f"{workDir}Z_WRx{dow}_x.gslides", f"{workDir}WR{chapter}{dow}_{topic}.gslides")
  chapter += 1

For each of these variants, Colab throws the same  error:
/usr/lib/python3.10/shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    252         os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    253     else:
--> 254         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    255             try:
    256                 with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:

OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Classes/RE190 World Rel/Slides/Z_WRx1_x.gslides'

It looks like it's having problems opening the file, rather than writing the output.

I've also tried using the shell cp function:
chapter = 3
topics = ['African','Hinduism']

for topic in topics:
  for dow in range(1,4):
    !cp "{workDir}Z_WRx{dow}_x.gslides" "{workDir}WR{chapter}{dow}_{topic}.gslides"

  chapter += 1

This generates a different error:
cp: cannot stat '/content/drive/MyDrive/Classes/RE190\ World Rel/Slides/Z_WRx1_x.gslides': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/content/drive/MyDrive/Classes/RE190\ World Rel/Slides/Z_WRx2_x.gslides': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/content/drive/MyDrive/Classes/RE190\ World Rel/Slides/Z_WRx3_x.gslides': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/content/drive/MyDrive/Classes/RE190\ World Rel/Slides/Z_WRx1_x.gslides': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/content/drive/MyDrive/Classes/RE190\ World Rel/Slides/Z_WRx2_x.gslides': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/content/drive/MyDrive/Classes/RE190\ World Rel/Slides/Z_WRx3_x.gslides': No such file or directory

So this is doing the loop OK, but again it is not finding the file.
Colab's AI agent says this should work.

Suggestions about what I'm doing wrong? Or is this just not supported by colab?

The problem may be because the folder name RE190 World Rel contains spaces.  Are you able to rename that folder to a different name that does not have spaces?

Or the problem may be that the google drive folder is mounted as a read-only folder.

@JohnGordon - Thanks for your response. I've changed the folder name to use underscores (RE190_World_Rel) rather than spaces. The same errors are generated.

How do I determine if I've mounted the folder as a RO folder? Or how do I mount it as a RW folder?

I think Colab defaults to RW access. This page https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA says that after mounting "This only supports reading, writing, and moving files; to programmatically modify sharing settings or other metadata, use one of the other options below."

These docs https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/info.html#info describe using fs to examine permissions. I did this and at least for the template file (Z_WRx1_x.gslides), Permissions(user='rw',group='',other='').

Are you also storing the files in question on Google Drive? Also, are they being stored within local storage? If so, can you open them manually? If they are being stored with Drive, please provide more details on how you are storing these. I would like to suggest that you try using the APIs Explorer tool in order to check if you can normally use the Google services.
